# How to make pages to move left or right after button was pressed(animation)?

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I am looking for way to make all pages move left,right,top,down. Everything is ok with down and up.Right and left dont work exectly like I want.There are white space between pages. I put all pages in a big container. I use three smaller containers(display flex). I hidden all pages. Only one we can see. When we move down and up we see fist child of next(last)container. When we move on sides we move to nextSubline.Part down and up works. But when sides move, I first see like page move than white screen and than a new page.Is any ideas why between two pages is white? I guess that problem is im my css transform. I gave not correct, but can't find way how I should make it.

```js
var down = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-arrow-down");

for (var i = 0; i < down.length; i++) {
    down[i].onclick = function showNext() {
        var parent = this.parentElement;
        var ourCont = parent.parentElement;
        var nextCont = ourCont.nextElementSibling;
        var pageToShow = nextCont.firstElementChild;
        var contToMove = ourCont.parentElement;

        function animationEnded() {
            contToMove.classList.remove('page-moveUp');
            parent.classList.remove('page-visible');
            contToMove.removeEventListener('animationend', animationEnded);
        }
        contToMove.addEventListener('animationend', animationEnded);
        pageToShow.classList.add('page-visible');
        contToMove.classList.add('page-moveUp');

    }
}

var up = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-arrow-up");

for (var i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
    up[i].onclick = function showLast() {
        var parent = this.parentElement;
        var ourCont = parent.parentElement;
        var lastCont = ourCont.previousElementSibling;
        var pageToShow = lastCont.firstElementChild;
        var contToMove = ourCont.parentElement;

        function animationEnded() {
            contToMove.classList.remove('page-moveDown');
            parent.classList.remove('page-visible');
            contToMove.removeEventListener('animationend', animationEnded);
        }
        contToMove.addEventListener('animationend', animationEnded);

        pageToShow.classList.add('page-visible');
        contToMove.classList.add('page-moveDown');


    }

}

var left = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-arrow-left");

for (var i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
    left[i].onclick = function showLeft() {
        var parent = this.parentElement;
        var maybeLeftToOpen = parent.previousElementSibling;
        var ourCont = parent.parentElement;
        var contToMove = ourCont.parentElement;
        var cls = maybeLeftToOpen.className;
        var clsarray = cls.split();

        for (var j = 0; j < clsarray.length; j++) {
            var name = clsarray[j];
            if (name = 'page') {
                var leftToOpen = maybeLeftToOpen;

                function animationEnded() {
                    contToMove.classList.remove('page-moveLeft');
                    parent.classList.remove('page-visible');
                    contToMove.removeEventListener('animationend', animationEnded);
                }

                contToMove.addEventListener('animationend', animationEnded);

                leftToOpen.classList.add('page-visible');
                contToMove.classList.add('page-moveLeft');

            }

        }
    }

}
var right = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-arrow-right");

for (var i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {
    right[i].onclick = function showRight() {
        var parent = this.parentElement;
        var maybeRightToOpen = parent.nextElementSibling;
        var ourCont = parent.parentElement;
        var contToMove = ourCont.parentElement;
        var cls = maybeRightToOpen.className;
        var clsarray = cls.split();
        for (var j = 0; j < clsarray.length; j++) {
            var name = clsarray[j];
            if (name = 'page') {
                var rightToOpen = maybeRightToOpen;

                function animationEnded() {
                    contToMove.classList.remove('page-moveRight');
                    parent.classList.remove('page-visible');
                    contToMove.removeEventListener('animationend', animationEnded);
                }
                contToMove.addEventListener('animationend', animationEnded);
                rightToOpen.classList.add('page-visible');
                contToMove.classList.add('page-moveRight');

            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;    
}
.container{   
    display: flex;   
}
.page{  
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh; 
    position: relative;  
    display: none;
}
.page-visible {
    display: block;
}
.q{
    background:purple;
}
.a{
    background:orange;
}
.z{
    background:red;
}
.w{
    background:brown;
}
.s{
    background:green;
}
.x{
    background:gray;
}
.e{
    background:rgb(42, 165, 83);
}
.d{
    background:rgb(91, 139, 91);
}
.c{
    background:rgb(168, 37, 37);
}
.up{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 47%;  
}
.down{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 47%;
}
.left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50px;

}
.right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;;
    right: 50px;  

}
span{
    cursor: pointer;
}


.page-moveUp {
    animation: moveUp 3s ease both;
  }
@keyframes moveUp {
 from {top:0px }
 to {transform: translateY(-100vh); }
}
.page-moveDown{
    animation: moveDown 3s ease both;
}
@keyframes moveDown {
    from{ transform: translateY(-100vh); }
    /* to {transform: translateY(0); } */
    to{top:0px}
}
.page-moveLeft{
    animation: moveLeft 6s ease both;
}
@keyframes moveLeft {
 from{transform: translateX(-100vw);}
 to {transform: translateX(0);}
}
.page-moveRight{
    animation: moveRight 6s ease both;
}
@keyframes moveRight {
 from{left:0}
 to {transform: translateX(-100vw);}
}
```

```html
<div class="super-container">
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="page q page-visible">
            <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page a">
           <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page z">
            <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="page w">
            <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page s">
            <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container3">
            <div class="page x">
            <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page e">
            <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page d">
            <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page c">
            <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake - should give flex to container1,container2,container3.